# How to handle existing data during MongoDB document creation?

Tags: database, mongodb, time-series

I have a mongodb database that is storing time-series data. Let's assume this is the data that is already in there.

```
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:35:00+00:00"
}
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:40:00+00:00"
}
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:45:00+00:00"
}
```

As you can see, what matters here is the `date` field.

After my API call, I receive some new data, that might look like that.

```
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:35:00+00:00"
}
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:40:00+00:00"
}
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:45:00+00:00"
}
{
    asset: "BTC/EUR",
    timeframe: "5m",
    stream: {O,H,L,C,V},
    date: "2020-06-18T11:50:00+00:00"
}
```

So, all the other 3 entries are already in the db, I just would like to add the data that is not in the db, in our case, the last entry dated `2020-06-18T11:50:00+00:00` - or potentially fill in any gaps in the previous records.

Do I need to pull all the previous entries from the db and compare them to my latest payload, then filter out the existing ones and then make my db entry?

This is how my schema looks:

[image]

Comment: Are they separate documents or part of an array?

Comment: Separate. Is this what you mean? https://ibb.co/wBNMR18 Each one of those is a separate entry in the db.

Comment: Do you have any other unique field in your db?

Comment: No. My schema looks like this: https://ibb.co/j5gp1qS I have `date: {unique: true}` in there. That seems to prevent entries with the same date for that particular collection.

Comment: I'm planning to put anything that increments by 5 minutes in a '5m' collection, and anything that increments by 15 minutes, in a '15m' collection. In this way I can have same date signatures in different collections as 5 minute and 15 minute intervals overlap every 15 minutes.